# Do you think polling is a good approach for other devices, such as a disk or a network interface?

Tags: lc3

Im learning LC3 but there are some problem i can not understand clearly

Answer (score 0):

Polling is a reasonable way to interact with a device, if the program doesn't have anything better to do than wait for that device.

This can be the case on simple systems, and some embedded systems work that way.

However, as we increase the system's workload, polling may become insufficiently responsive to the devices and/or programs, so other methods perform better.

Interrupts are an alternative to polling.  Interrupts mechanisms support prioritization both in hardware and in software.

When I/O devices are ready simultaneously/concurrently, the hardware will prioritize the devices, effectively by their device speed. This means that fast devices can get the attention of the CPU quickly in response to data being ready.

When the CPU is servicing a low priority device and a higher priority device becomes ready, with interrupts, software can layer so as to allow higher priority devices to interrupt lower priority (slower) devices that may be currently being serviced.

Interrupts also work well when many programs compete for the CPU.

In summary, the more devices and more programs, the worse that polling will perform, potentially slowing the system down and even loosing data from devices.  Interrupts, when properly layered, can mitigate these issues.